# openssl pkcs12 keeps removing the PEM passphrase from keystore's entry?

Tags: certificate, openssl, rsa, pki, pkcs

> OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

Generating a self-signed certificate:

> openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days
>   365

During the process a **PEM passphrase** is requested:

> Enter PEM pass phrase:
>   Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:

There are 2 resulting files after successful completion in **PEM** format:

**key.pem, cert.pem**

The private key (**key.pem**) is in **PKCS#8** format and the starting line reads:

> -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

Now I am trying to combine the certificate, as well as the related private key, into a **PKCS#12** keystore and protect the keystore with a **password**. Note - from my understanding this should effectively enforce requesting a **password** during read access, as well as a **passphrase** for the private key of the according entry:

> openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem -out keystore.p12

Upon execution I am asked of the following:

> Enter pass phrase for key.pem:
>   Enter Export Password:
>   Verifying - Enter Export Password:

However, it is my understanding that the **passphrase** should remain intact for the **private key** that is now being stored in the **keystore.p12** file. Here is how I try to read the contents of the keystore:

> openssl pkcs12 -nodes -info -in keystore.p12

The output I get (only related to protecting the keystore with a **password**):

> Enter Import Password:

And lists the certificate, as well as the private key, in PEM format without requesting the **passphrase** for the latter. That is basically the problem. The **PEM passphrase** is no longer there for the **private key**. What am I doing wrong or how can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong. That's how PKCS12 works. PKCS12 is format for securely transporting certificate chains and private keys between tokens. Protection/encryption of private key is done by passphrase you entered when asked for 'Enter Export Password'. Nothing like twice encrypted keys.

EDIT: Omit `-nodes` option. That turns off encryption of private key.

Comment: I am pretty sure I was prompted to enter a **PEM passphrae** once when I **-info** on a couple of **.p12** files (I can't seem to replicate the exact steps I performed to trigger it though, hence why I posted)

Comment: Try the same with NSS certutil and pk12util... you will get the same behavior as I mentioned. If was asked for *PEM pass*, it was when you were exporting things from PKCS12... and storing them encoded in PEM format. *-info* is `give info about PKCS#12 structure`, not export.

Comment: I am only using **-info** to list the contents of the keystore and I assure you that I was requested to enter a **PEM** passphrase when doing so (I am not dreaming, hence why I'm giving out bounty on this question) - **SafeBag** containers **should** carry a password aswell.

Comment: Coincidentally I had to do some cert updates yesterday and realized what your questions is about... answer above in edit.

Comment: I think you cracked it :) I've only got 1 question left - is **JKS** expected to behave the same way, as in, it also doesn't support protecting cert/privkey pairs with a standalone password? Maybe you've come across it aswell at some point by chance